# Icons have poor clarity in Xamarin forms UWP project

Tags: xamarin.forms, uwp, icons

I am using 24x24 pixels icons in my xamarin forms UWP project, but not getting good clarity when it comes in UI. For Android, I am using 4 set of icons for different devices and 3 set for IOS. **How many sets of icons are needed for UWP and what is the resolution for those icons?**

Comment: I have all my UWP icons set to 48x48, try doing the same.

Comment: @sme Is that working fine in windows pc, windows phone and windows tablet?

Comment: PC and phone, never tested on tablet.

Comment: @sme Please post it as your answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How many sets of icons are needed for UWP and what is the resolution for those icons?

Every app has an icon/logo that represents it, and that icon appears in multiple locations in the Windows shell:

- The title bar of your app window
- The app list in the start menu
- The taskbar and task manager
- Your app's tiles
- Your app's splash screen
- In the Microsoft Store

We have detailed article that specifically for icons that represent the app itself. please check [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/style/app-icons-and-logos) and use the suitable size icon.